# Onecoin vs Bitcoin

Tags: fraud

I have recently heard about this kind of crypto-valute and I would like to know from experts qualified informations and suggestions. Sincerely, I know very little about the world of the Bitcoin so I would like to know the differences between the two, if there are, and the potential risks and revenues. 
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: "I know very little about the world of the Bitcoin" For your own sake: please stay away from ANY and ALL altcoins and "blockchain" projects until you feel confident that you know enough about Bitcoin itself and are able to judge the claims made by altcoins. In practice 99% or more are scam or otherwise nonsense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bitcoin is sound technology, but somewhat hard to understand encompassingly. Due to the amount of money that is involved, numerous ponzi-schemes and other scams have sprung up in its vicinity.

From what I've read, and the recount of another Bitcoin meetup member that went to a OneCoin presentation: **OneCoin appears to be a pyramid scheme** aimed at people that know little to nothing about cryptocurrency, feeding off of the news attention Bitcoin et al. are generating.

Please apply a healthy amount of skepticism when offered any form of cryptocurrency investment. If it sounds too good to be true, it probably is. When in doubt, please ask about specific products on platforms dedicated to the discussion of cryptocurrencies. Personally, I'll stay away from OneCoin as far as I can.

Related News:

- [One Coin, Much Scam: OneCoin Exposed as Global MLM Ponzi Scheme](http://cointelegraph.com/news/one-coin-much-scam-onecoin-exposed-as-global-mlm-ponzi-scheme).
- [OneCoin investment warning issued by Bank of Hungary](http://behindmlm.com/companies/onecoin-investment-warning-issued-by-bank-of-hungary/)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this posting there are no merchants accepting onecoin in contrast to bitcoin and the other altcoins. Aside from what Murch has said there are no information provided by the onecoin group verifiable in another independent source. 
It seems to me all the information provided by onecoin users are provided by their website which does not stand up to scrutiny.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Ponzi scheme. Stop screwing up people's lives.

There gonna be real losers real soon.

- There is no business model.
- There is no coin mining.
- New member money is used to pay commissions.
- When new members dry up, then, where will you generate income from?
- Nobody, i.e. not one merchant, is accepting Onecoin.

Stupid scheme.

Answer (score -4):

people should let onecoin be thier intension is pure the ceo's ideology and strategy is reasonable. i wont be suprise if westblock elements are aiding these propaganda. users remener onecoin has a new block chain now.please checkout the advantges. cheers

Comment: This isn't an answer. You should list the advantages you see in Onecoin over Bitcoin and the other way around as OP asked for a comparison. Furthermore, you didn't talk about the risks associated with Onecoin which probably is what OP is very interested in.

Comment: @UTF-8: I still think that this should not be deleted. While it is not a direct answer, I think that it does useful in coming to a conclusion about differences between Bitcoin and OneCoin.